# Make element stay to the right even when scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a "red colored" element which should always stay to the right. With to the right I mean to the right of the parent `lime colored border` element. "Normally" setting the parent to `position: relative;` and the child to `position: absolute; right: 0;` does the trick but not in this case.

Anyone telling me why and how to fix it?

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid div[class*='col-'] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-grow: 0.33;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0%;
    border: solid 1px lime;
}

.resize-bar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

[data-resizable] {
    min-width: 5px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover on "orange" and scroll horizontally</h2>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1-4" data-resizable="true">
      <div style="width:300px;height:40px;background-color:orange;"></div>
      <span class="resize-bar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If possible a non javascript solution will be preferred. Thank you.

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrcf2e8u/4/)

Comment: Can't you place the resize bar outside the parent element? that should fix your issue.

Comment: @Mr_Green-divami.com not really. Then I wouldn't know where to place the resize-bar cause the `col-1-4` can have different widths and there can be multiple `col-1-4` elements.

Comment: Add a `border-right: solid 5px red;` after the `border: solid 1px lime;`. Remove the `<span class="resize-bar"></span>` from your markup.

Comment: Is flex required?

Comment: @Dimash yes it is.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos the `resize-bar` is there for a reason. I can not just remove it cause the CSS does not what I want ;)

Comment: That's stupid. You need change structure, you really give already designed element with 1 bar to move. We even do not know if you can set px sizes or not.  I would not recommend to use flex here at all, in other way it can be fixed very simply if you want scalable object based on vw, vh or em, rem, but flex fails in all cases per pure relative positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrcf2e8u/5/)

wrap content in another `div`, which same size of `col-`

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid div[class*='col-'] {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 0.33;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: solid 1px lime;
}

.resize-bar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    min-width: 5px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover on "orange" and scroll horizontally</h2>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1-4" data-resizable="true">
    <div class="box">
      <div style="width:370px;height:40px;background-color:orange;">

      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="resize-bar"></span>
  </div>
      
 
</div>
```